# When hovering over low-rep user name, please show "member since" and other basic info

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice, when hovering over the names of users with low reputation (let's say 100 or less) to see how long they've been a member, and maybe how many questions they've asked and answered.

Why? So the comment on a question or a close vote can have a little more context. For example, I like to say "Welcome to Stack Overflow; great question!" if that's appropriate, or "Welcome to Stack Overflow; this question needs ... whatever"

The comment I write might be subtly different if the member has been lurking for a few months than if they joined today.

Now, to get that context, I have to click through to the member's (mostly empty) profile. It would be sweet to know just enough to write a helpful welcome comment, without those extra clicks.

So, SE team, **please consider adding this new member hover feature.**

Why do I care? It's community building. I've seen terrific stuff on here from new members, and we were all n00bz once.

Comment: As you said, it would only save you a few clicks. On the other hand, it would advertise the user as being "new", with all the problems that usually entails (remember the "acceptance rate" metric we had once). Oh, and please don't post comments like *Welcome to Stack Overflow; great question!* -- these are just noise.

Comment: If you must...why not use the [***Chrome Extension***](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and customise the "Welcome Message".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a good idea.

It could be used as a reason not to answer a user's question, when a potential answerer sees the OP only registered that day, or never posted something before.

Comment: How is registration date related to answering? If user asks his first questions an year after the registration whould it be more likely answered if he asked his first question in the day of registration? Seems like no.

Comment: Users can be reluctant to answer questions posted by new users, as those may be unaware of how SO works in regards to voting / accepting answers. Advertising that a user is new doesn't benefit anyone.

Comment: I think, it more likely depends on rep (the user with 1 point for example) than the fact how long have he been registered.

Comment: Users can get 2k rep without ever answering / asking, though.